# .slideToggle() not working when using Jquery 3.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

For some reason I am getting an Uncaught TypeError when I try and execute the following code.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".block").click(function() {
            var currentElement = $(this).find(".form-group");
            currentElement.slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: currentElement.slideToggle is not a function
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (index.js:6)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
```

However when I call `currentElement.toggle()` It works as expected and I do not get any errors.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is you are using the **slim** version which excludes the effects like the animation expected from `slideToggle`; so the function isn't defined. Just switch to the normal version.

From the [Jquery Page](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/)

> **Slim build** 
> Sometimes you don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many standalone libraries that focus on ajax requests. And often it is simpler to use a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all your web animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the ajax and effects modules, we’ve released a “slim” version that excludes these modules. All in all, it excludes ajax, effects, and currently deprecated code.

Comment: Thank you!! I used the template that bootstrap gives you and for some reason they were linking the slim version!