# Object doesn't support property or method 'slideToggle' in MS Edge called from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microsoft-edge

I am trying to slideToggle a div with "main-nav" id from an iframe:

```
<div id="top">
  <div id="titlearea">
    <iframe id="customnavbar" src="navbar/navbar.html">..</iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="main-nav">...</div>
</div>
```

but I am getting an Error: `0:Object doesn't support property or method 'slideToggle'`.

I am using this onClick event handler for a.dropdown-toggle link:

```
$(function(){
  $("a.dropdown-toggle").on("click", function(){
    $("#main-nav", window.parent.document).slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

I am testing in Microsoft Edge 44.18362.267.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362 .
I am loading jQuery library before my script attaches the onClick eventhandler.

I tried `$("#main-nav", window.parent.document).slideToggle(300);` in the edge console and it works correctly.

Any ideas what could be the problem here? Thanks.

**EDIT**

After pushing my code to github I tested it in chrome and got this Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slideToggle is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.myEventHandler (navbar.html:48)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
myEventHandler @ navbar.html:48
dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
```

**SOLUTION**

Then I found out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653512/slidetoggle-not-working-when-using-jquery-3-1-1).

The problem was in including `slim minified` version of jQuery, changing this to just `minified` version helped.

Comment: Are both documents on the same domain?

Comment: They are both on local storage. That's why I am testing on Edge as chrome does count this as cross-domain access. Anyway, I am also resizing one div from the iframe and that works flawlessly.

Comment: From your edit in the original post, It looks like you had found the solution for your issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653512/slidetoggle-not-working-when-using-jquery-3-1-1).

The problem is in including **slim minified** version of jQuery, changing this to just **minified** version solves the issue.